# CodeDeploy on autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've set up an auto scaling group behind a load balancer and i've created applications in codedeploy, that are deployed on each server.
Actually we have 5 applications, but two of these, are laravel based apps so there's the need to install all composer stuff and npm modules before deployment.
Unfortunately this leads to a deployment that lasts more than 5 minutes and codedeploy sets the deployment as failed and the instance is terminated. 
Does anyone have any idea or suggestion on how to solve this issue ?

These are commands that take long time

`sudo -H -u $WANTUSER /usr/local/bin/composer update -d "/var/www/mydomain.com/orderform/designer/Designer_php"`

`sudo -H -u $WANTUSER /usr/bin/npm --prefix 
/var/www/mydomain.com/orderform/designer/Designer_php install`

Answer (score 0):

In your CodeDeploy hook definition, you need to increase the timeout value.